# array_column returning 0 results from an array with data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have some data coming into a page with multiple rows and columns.  I am specifically looking to take 1 entire column and put it into another array.

I am using codeigniter and php.  The var dump on my page shows that the data in its raw array is arriving just fine.  But once I start to try and create a second array on the page, the array returns 0 results.

Here is the var_dump for the original array. For your sanity, ill only post the first sequence.

> array(7) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["serial_number"]=> string(9) "battery 1" ["battery_type"]=> string(4)
>   "Lipo" ["cell_count"]=> string(1) "4" ["capacity"]=> string(4) "16.8"
>   ["date_submitted"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
>   ["user_id_submitted"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=>

Here is the **array_column** function

```
<?php 
    $serialnumber = array_column($batteryDb, "serial_number");
    var_dump($serialnumber);
?>
```

and here is the result:

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: Well, seems that `$batteryDb` has not the right structure. It has to be an array of arrays. Would you be so nice to add the output of `var_dump($batteryDb);` to your original post - maybe just two items.

Comment: @JustinSellers Edit your OP to include your sample array data.

Comment: I just updated it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, `var_dump($batteryDb);` shows this:

```
array(7) { 
 [0] => object(stdClass)#19 (7) {                     <----- object  !!
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["serial_number"]=> string(9) "battery 1" 
    ["battery_type"]=> string(4) "Lipo" 
    ["cell_count"]=> string(1) "4" 
    ["capacity"]=> string(4) "16.8" 
    ["date_submitted"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
    ["user_id_submitted"]=> string(0) "" }
 [1] =>
```

---

The problem is that this array structure isn't working with `array_column` on PHP5.

You have an array of objects, but the function expects an array of arrays.

An array of objects on `array_column` is only supported by PHP7. 
Referencing: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.0/UPGRADING#L626

---

The basic solution would be to turn your objects into arrays:

```
array(7) { 
     [0] => array (7) {                              <----- array !!
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
```

You can do that using:

- `$array = (array) $object;`
- `$array = get_object_vars($object);`
- if multi-dimensional: `$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);`

Give this a try:

```
$batteryDbArray = json_decode(json_encode($batteryDb), true);

$serial_numbers = array_column($batteryDbArray, 'serial_number');
var_dump($serial_numbers);
```

Comment: ok, so I gave that a try.  it rendered this   array(7) { [0]=> string(9) "battery 1" [1]=> string(9) "battery 2" [2]=> string(9) "battery 3" [3]=> string(9) "battery 5" [4]=> string(9) "battery 6" [5]=> string(9) "battery 4" [6]=> string(9) "battery 7" }

Comment: Now to figure out how to put those into a drop down list. haha

Answer (score 1):

I think [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) only added support for an array of Objects in 7.0, so you can try upgrading PHP or use a different method.

Try [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$serial_numbers = array_map(function($e) {
  return is_object($e) ? $e->serial_number : $e['serial_number'];
}, $batteryDb);
```

There are other, worse, solutions, such as using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)([json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)()) or iterating the array converting `stdClass` to `array` objects with [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) or casting, but I think these add unnecessary overhead and are less obvious:

```
$serial_numbers = array_column(json_decode(json_encode($batteryDb), true), 'serial_number'));
```